# Photoshop - Color Picker Box?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I make this:

[image]

Look like this:

[image]

The color picker; how do I make it a giant box rather than a thin rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the tiny menu icon to the top right of the Color palette, and choose the *Hue Cube* option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I presume if you're using **Adobe CC** you'll find **Hue Cube** option to enable it.

**Hue Cube** option is not available in CS6. If you still want it, I'd recommend picking up the plugin [Coolours](https://coolorus.com/)